# position of top-menu after search- bar

Tags: magento2

Position need to change of  `top menu` after the search bar in magento2.

Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

For Magento2 default theme (Luma) go to below this path:

magento2/vendor/magento/theme-frontend-luma/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml

And add this code before the body end:

```
 <move element="navigation.sections" destination="header-wrapper" after="top.search" />
```

Comment: This is not work sir